# PHP 5.4 interactive mode on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ppa, php

I'm a big fan of PHP interactive mode (`php -a`). Today I decided to install PHP 5.4 to play around a little bit. It's fun to use the new built-in server and all that stuff, but I was very sad when I discovered that the interactive mode doesn't work.

I installed PHP 5.4 on my Ubuntu by adding the PPA:

```
add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php5
apt-get update
apt-get install php5
```

And this is what I get when I run `php -a`:

```
$ php -a
Interactive mode enabled
```

Aaaaand nothing more. As far as I know this PPA follows the newest PHP5 maintained by Debian PKG PHP Team and as far as I know the interactive mode is also usually broken on freshly installed Debians.

Any ideas on how to get it back? Preferably using some other PPA or at least without compiling - that's usually less painful.

Comment: Well, for the moment I will stick with [phpsh](http://phpsh.org/)

Comment: I suppose this has to do with Debian linking against `libreadline` instead of `libedit` for licensing issues. See [Debian bug #576218](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=576218).

Comment: Yeah, I've heard something about that. Just wanted to know if someone knows some good PPA to use =/

Comment: BTW it's the other way around.  libreadline is licensed under GPL with is not compatible with basically anything else than GPL, so PHP has to be compiled with libedit (and there was a bug in libedit...)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

My PPA (ppa:ondrej/php5) was created as an exact copy of Debian php5 source package.  There was a problem that Debian's libedit didn't include the required patch for interactive mode (at least I thought so, because the bug on libedit wasn't closed).  I have just found that this issue has been already solved in libedit (2.11-20080614-4), but the bug wasn't properly closed.

Anyway the good news is that since this bug in libedit has been already solved in Debian, I will be rebuilding php5 with libedit and it will be included from php5 >= 5.4.12-2(~dist+1).

[Edit]: Also there's now php5-readline module, thanks to Andreas Pour, who poked me that it can be built and packaged now.

Comment: JFTR There was a problem with backporting libedit to lucid, so it took a while before I was able to pinpoint to root cause of the link failures.  Anyway this is solved now and i386 php5 on lucid was successfully built and amd64 should be ready later today.

Answer (score 8):

I've just solved the problem here, a few minutes ago installing the readline module for php5:

```
$ apt-get install php5-readline
$ php -a
php>
```

Now it works fine. Don't know about windows, sorry.

Comment: The question was about linux. Ondřej (@oerdnj) already mentioned readline. Thanks anyway :)