# PHP cli hangs after ppa update to 5.5

Tags: command-line, apache2, php, ppa, php-cli

I remember having the exact same problem on my other machine, and I know I fixed in then, but I don't remember how...

After installing php/apache/mysql/phpmyadmin from the usual repositories, I added `ppa:ondrej/php5` and `ppa:ondrej/apache2`, and upgraded everything in order to use PHP 5.5.

Now, when I type `php -a` in console, the shell hangs after printing `Interactive mode enabled` and I have no prompt. How do I get my CLI back?

Comment: I don't think it "hangs", it just doesn't have the readline capabilities.  I will add Recommends: php5-readline to php5-cli package, that should solve the most scenarios.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ahh I knew I saw that somewhere:
[PHP 5.4 interactive mode on Ubuntu 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/228274/php-5-4-interactive-mode-on-ubuntu-12-04)

For the record, the solution is:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-readline
```